# Keras input dim error

Tags: keras, openai-gym

while Iam experimenting with keras and Gym of Openai and I keep getting this error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected reshape_1_input to have shape (None, 979, 1) but got array with shape (979, 1, 1)
```

I gather my Data as follow:

```
def getData():
    rewardc = 0
    rewardo = 0
    labels = np.array([])
    data = np.array([])
    for i in range(11):
        print("run",i)
        for _ in range (10000):
            print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("action", _)
            #env.render()
            action = env.action_space.sample()
            observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            if done:
                env.reset()
                break
            rewardc = rewardo - reward
            rewardo = reward
            observationo = observation
            rewardco = rewardc
            ohobservation = np.array(observationo)
            ohobservation = np.append(ohobservation, rewardo)
            ohobservation = np.append(ohobservation, rewardco)
            #print ("whole observation",ohobservation)
            #print("data", data)
            labelsb = np.array([action])
            if labels.size == 0:
                labels = labelsb
            else:
                labels = np.vstack((labels,action))
            if data.size == 0:
                data = ohobservation
            else:
                data = np.vstack((data, ohobservation))

    return labels, data
```

My x array will look like that:

```
[ [2]  [0]  [2]  [3]  [0]  [0]  ..  [2]  [3]]
```

My Y:

```
  Y [[  1.15792274e-02   9.40991027e-01   5.85608387e-01 ...,   0.00000000e+00
   -5.27112172e-01   5.27112172e-01]
 [  1.74466133e-02   9.40591342e-01   5.95346880e-01 ...,   0.00000000e+00
   -1.88372436e+00   1.35661219e+00]
 [  2.32508659e-02   9.39789397e-01   5.87415648e-01 ...,   0.00000000e+00
   -4.41631844e-02  -1.83956118e+00]
```

Network Code:

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units= 64,  input_dim= 100))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(units=10))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X,Y, epochs=5)
```

But I cannot feed it in Keras at any Chance.
It would be awesome if somebody could help me solve it thank you!

Comment: Need to see your network code

Comment: Maybe you need to reshape the input data as `(1,979,1)`.

Comment: It could, @Craig.Li, but it looks like the input layer is a reshape layer, so its hard to tell what OP is doing without the code

Comment: added Neural Network code

Answer (score 0):

**Inputs**

If your data is 979 examples, each example containing one element, make sure that its first dimension is 979

```
print(X.shape) #confirm that the shape is (979,1) or (979,)
```

If the shape is different from that, you will have to reshape the array, because the `Dense` layer expects shapes in those forms.

```
X = X.reshape((979,))
```

Now, make sure that your Dense layer is compatible with that shape:

```
 #using input_dim:
 Dense(units=64, input_dim=1) #each example has only one element

 #or, using input_shape:
 Dense(units=64, input_shape=(1,)) #input_shape must always be a tuple. Again, the number of examples shouldn't be a part of this shape
```

This will solve the problems you have with the **inputs**. All the error messages you get like this one are about the compatibility between your input data and the input shape you gave to the first layer:

```
Error when checking input: expected reshape_1_input to have shape (None, 979, 1) 
but got array with shape (979, 1, 1)
```

The first shape in the message is the `input_shape` you passed to the layer. The second is the shape of your actual data.

**Outputs**

The same compatibility is necessary for Y, but now with the **last layer**.

If you put `units=10` in the last layer, it means your labels must be of shape (979,10).

If your labels don't have that shape, adjust the number of cells to match it.

Comment: It's case 2, how can I do that?

Comment: `input_shape = (1,1)`. Or even better, if your model does start with a dense layer, just `input_shape=(1,)` is ok, as long as `x.shape=(979examples,1)`.

Comment: sorry with while working on it I came on the Error:     "ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (None, 10) but got array with shape (1234, 1)" but I cannot fix it. Can you help, please? This happens while fitting, because of that I can use just 1 layer

Comment: Why did you change `input_shape` to 10? It should be `(1,)`. The shape of your data.

Comment: I think thats because my X has (1,) but my Y is (10,)(because of multiple datapoints at one time

Comment: Y is output, it has to do with the last layer only. `Dense(10)` is ok to generate (None, 10) targets.

Comment: so should I make X to Y and Y to X? Or what should I do?

Comment: `input_shape` must match X, the last layer must match Y.

Comment: So in the last layer an input_shape, too?

Comment: No, the last layer is ok as `Dense(10)`. It has 10 cells, it will have 10-shaped outputs. -- The error message says "input".

Comment: So what would you suggest to do?

Comment: So what can I do? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I get this error now : "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_2 to have shape (None, 8) but got array with shape (930, 1)" with network code " model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(units=102, input_dim=10))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
 model.add(Dense(units=8, input_dim=1))
 model.add(Activation('softmax'))
 model.compile(optimizer="Adam",loss = "binary_crossentropy")
 model.fit(X,Y, epochs=20, verbose=2, validation_split=0.2)"                           thank you

Comment: In the message: "target" means output. --- The "Expected something to have `(None, 8)`" is the shape of the output of your model. Why 8?? Because you have your last important layer as a `Dense(8)`. --- The "but got `(930,1)`" means that your Y (true data) has only one element per sample, not 8. --- Make the last layer match your true data: `Dense(1,...)`

Comment: So, what is correct, 8 or 1? -- How many classes are you supposed to predict? If it's 1, you will also need to use `sigmoid` and `binary_crossentropy` (not `softmax`)

Comment: It gets 10 variables per input in and it should output just one variable form 1-3

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: Can you give me a Suggestion? Please

Comment: Read everything again carefully. All these errors are the same: you have input data as numpy arrays. And you have an input_shape to the model, and an output shape (that you can see in the model.summary()). --- Make sure that your arrays have their shapes compatible with the shapes of the model.